# Bootstrap 3 broken row on mobile only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with bootstrap 3 and some thumbnails where although I'm using the same code and the image sizes are exactly the same the last image row is broken on mobile when in vertical only

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="?service=4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-1_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">styling</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="?service=5">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-2_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">colour</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="?service=6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-3_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">extensions</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="?service=7">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-4_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">hair enhancements</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="?service=8">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-5_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">smoothing treatment</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="?service=9">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-6_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">hair up</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="meet-the-team">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-7_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">meet the team</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/price-list/">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://mysite/tn-8_256x300.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-center text_margin">price list</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end container-->
```

Comment: Don't you have a padding or margin below your "smoothing treatment" title ? It seems really close to break the floating alignment.

Comment: It could be that you have set a height for the image containers. Then, the image with the title occupying 2 lines is exceding the available height which causes the image container bellow being pushed to the right.

Comment: I just checked it with firebug and it looks like wordpress is automatically giving it a height and width :o/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because some of the text below the thumbnails is wrapping, and as a result the thumbnail heights are different. One way to fix this problem is to clear the columns float on mobile with CSS like this..

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .row > .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

Demo 1: http://codeply.com/go/Bgt8JFkPht

Another option (simpler), is to use CSS text-overflow ellipsis on the text DIV's since it's these DIVs that are causing the height to be different on each thumbnail. When the thumbnail heights are the same, the row wrapping is not an issue..

Demo 2: http://codeply.com/go/5uOP4bM5pk

Answer (score -2):

Check your **text-margin** class, when adding a margin or padding to some items in Bootstrap, you change the width of your columns.

Comment: I've removed every single inline css that I added and the text is still going on top of the thumbnail