# Bootstrap panels being pushed down with too much text in heading

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've just been watching some videos trying to learn how to use Bootstrap, it's going fine until i started adding too much text into the panel-heading.

Here is the code (repeated several times)

```
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                        <div class="panel panel-red">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <p>Game Name - US</p>
                            </div>


                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="media text-center" style="padding:10px;">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="images/3DS1247.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" /></a>
                                        <div class="margin"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-center" type="button">Game Info</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span>Added on 2015-03-31</span>

                                <div class="clearfix">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
```

This is what's happening, should just be 2 rows of 3.

[image]

Comment: It works with the code that you have: http://www.bootply.com/CU8ihDIiCm Please check if any other rules are overriding it. Post the full code.

Comment: Ah sorry, it works when it just says "game name - us" but if you extend the game name on some it messes it up.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question here: [Bootstrap 3 broken row on mobile only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812574/bootstrap-3-broken-row-on-mobile-only/31007914)

One option is to use a css clearfix every 3 cols:

### [Codeply link](http://codeply.com/go/Ffrwvu8aPE)

Another options is to truncate the heading text on smaller screens to prevent wrapping (which will make each panel the same height):

### [Codeply Link](http://codeply.com/go/igzONl50Az)

Comment: It's doing it on all browser sizes, Not just mobile. I think the clearfix every 3 cols will work though. however when it goes smaller res there is only 2 cols, so what can i do there?

Comment: Is there a gap with 2 cols, or you don't want 2 cols?

Answer (score 1):

```
.equateRow, .equateRow > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
/*add a class of equateRow around in the row that has the panels and you are good to go*/
```

### [Found a good bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/127828#)

Comment: So add this row within the other row?