# Bootstrap Footer Column/Row issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a footer on a Bootstrap website, which has 4 items in columns in its row - this display's correctly on desktop screens.

For mobile screen's I want it to change it to display 2 items, with the other 2 items below this - and the formatting of 1 item is all screwy.

Here's an image of the Footer on a desktop.
[image]

And here's an image of the footer for a small screen (i.e: mobile)
[image]

In the small screen image, the "accredited" image should be somewhat inline with the "We're Social" lines of text, and not below it.
Ive tried changing the column sizes (i.e: making "Accredited" = col-xs-7 & col-sm-7 and "We're Social" = col-xs-5 & col-sm-5), but its made no difference.

any suggestions as to where the issue lies?

Here's the HTML code for my footer:

```
<!-- ========= START FOOTER ========== -->
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <a href="http://www.acnc.gov.au/" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/ACNC-Charity-Logo.png" alt="ACNC Charity" width="150" height="150"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
        <h4><strong>Contact Us</strong></h4>
        <ul class='list-unstyled'>
          <li><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-globe'></i> 67-71 Strathallan Rd, Macleod, Victoria</li>
          <li><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-phone'></i> (03) 9450 7600</li>
          <li><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i> <a href='mailto:office@openhousecic.org.au'>office@openhousecic.org.au</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
        <h4><strong>We're Social</strong></h4>
        <ul class='list-unstyled'>
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/openhousecic/" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClFV3cZ3_e4u3O0zEmYun3w" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/open-house-cic" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/146218711@N02" target="_blank">Flickr</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <!--<div class="blank-gap-20"></div>-->
        <a href="http://www.qip.com.au/" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/QIP-logo.png" alt="QIP logo" width="150" height="83"></a>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- End Row -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <span>Open House Christian Involvement Centres &copy; 2017 : Website by <a href="http://www.bliss.net.au" target="_blank">Bliss</a></span>
        <div class="blank-gap-10"></div>
        <p><i>We acknowledge and pay respect to the Traditional Owners of the lands upon which Open House Christian Involvement Centres are situated.</i><p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- End row -->
  </div>  <!--- End Container -->
</footer>
```

And my site is using the 'Sticky-Footer' CSS for Bootstrap;

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 330px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: auto;
  min-height:200px;
  background-color: #f1eeee;
  color: #333
  /*color: #f9f9f9;*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [responsive reset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) as the columns are different height because of the content is each column. Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812574/bootstrap-3-broken-row-on-mobile-only/31007914).

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        ..
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
         ..
      </div>
      <div class="visible-sm visible-xs clearfix"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
       ..
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        ..
      </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/m5nWYTYa4H